# Unable to Find Tensorflow Module in Jupyter Notebooks Despite Being Installed

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

Been running in circles for a couple hours here. Using Python 3 in Jupyter notebooks, tensorflow 2.3.1 is installed (confirmed by running pip freeze).

When I attempt to import tensorflow though:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     63   try:
---> 64     from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     65   # This try catch logic is because there is no bazel equivalent for py_extension.

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-d6579f534729> in <module>
----> 1 import tensorflow

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
     39 import sys as _sys
     40 
---> 41 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     42 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
     43 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>
     38 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import,g-bad-import-order,g-import-not-at-top
     39 
---> 40 from tensorflow.python.eager import context
     41 
     42 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py in <module>
     33 from tensorflow.core.protobuf import config_pb2
     34 from tensorflow.core.protobuf import rewriter_config_pb2
---> 35 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe
     36 from tensorflow.python import tf2
     37 from tensorflow.python.client import pywrap_tf_session

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py in <module>
     26 
     27 # pylint: disable=invalid-import-order,g-bad-import-order, wildcard-import, unused-import
---> 28 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     29 from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tfe import *

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     81 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     82 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 83   raise ImportError(msg)
     84 
     85 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\REDACTED\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>

    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I have deleted and reinstalled the tensorflow module as well.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: can you do `which jupyter` before running jupyter notebook to find out if you are running the right jupyter notebook.
Also, you can try `!pip install tensorflow` inside the notebook to install tensorflow in env of your jupyter notebook.

Comment: Thank you for the response, Jupyter Notebook 6.0.0. Even running "!pip install tensorflow" within the same notebook leads to the error.

Comment: maybe this would help (updated link): 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/39007

Answer (score 1):

The error is because Tensorflow requires Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015,2017,2019 as shown in the installation step on the [Tensorflow.org](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#1.-install-the-python-development-environment-on-your-system)